# What are some good English mathematics exercises textbooks at the level of South East Asia high school programs?

Tags: calculus, geometry, algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, logarithms

I live in this region and is studying to retake the national test and I need a big amount of tough exercises to practice but I can't find good documents/ textbooks over here. Any appropriate textbooks help me greatly. The topics are: calculus, algebra (especially logarithm), complex numbers, Oxyz algebra(?) (I really don't know what to call this one. It includes the equations of lines, planes, spheres, etc. And vector formulas. No matrices.). Thanks for your help.

Comment: It depends on the exam that you are going to take, so I think it helps if you provide some instanes of the problems. If you are looking for challenging problems, I think JEE books may help you.

Comment: And I think problmes of the previous exams are the best resource for pracricing if you can access them.

Comment: What you call “Oxyz algebra” is usually just called vector algebra.

Comment: @Etemon Since a few years ago, the test is a multiple-choice test and is annual so there aren't that many previous test to practice with (only 8). Also, the test consists of 50 questions but in fact only 7 or 8 of them are the deciding factors, since I have a high aim I need a great deal of such problems to train my ability to solve new and tough or obscure problems in sufficient time to achieve the score I want. I can provide some instants that I think encapsulate the main types of those problems (in my personal opinion):

Comment: @Etemon 1. The obscure but not so hard. Exp: given a bi-quadratic polynomial f(x), let g(x) be ln[f(x)]. With the graph of g(x) follows: +∞ - ln(12) - ln(199/16) - ln(4) - +∞. What is the area in between of f'(x) and g'(x)?
2. The hard - hard. Exp: In a Oxyz space, let (S) be a sphere with I(1;4;2) be its center and the radius = 2. Let M and N be 2 point on Ox and Oy respectively and MN touches (S) at on point. The circumscribed sphere of the tetrahedron OIMN has radius = 7/2. Let A be the point at which MN touches (S), what is the value of AM.AN?

Comment: 3. The hard and obscure. Exp: Consider all real number x and y that satisfy 8^(9-y^2) >= a^(6x-log2 of (a^3)), a is a real number. What is the minimum value of x^2 + y^2 -6x -8y?
I think those are all to the types of questions I'm looking for. I would be really thankful if you can suggest any source on them. Thank you.

Comment: @VươngThuật Couldn't really follow the problems. But it doesn't matter I was in a similar situation years ago. I recommend first of all try to learn the subjects of the exam deeply it is the most important thing. Then increase your problem solving skills by solving many problems and learn the ideas and increase your speed. I'm from Iran and not a JEE aspirant but I found some of JEE preparation's books challenging and interesting here is an example of such books: https://kupdf.net/download/advanced-problems-in-algebra-by-vikas-gupta_62f07c70e2b6f5de2f414e26_pdf

Comment: @DavidH - "analytic geometry" is more likely the English term. "Vector Algebra" is more concerned with linearity, not the equations of non-linear geometric objects.